# Selendroid - How to run test script?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can I run test using selendroid when device connected using WIFI? Or I will have to connect device using USB cable and then test will run?

I have created script just need help to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can connect device over WIFI.

Refer [this article](http://stuffandtech.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-quick-tip-adb-over-wifi.html) for more details.

Comment: Are you able to open link? I am getting blank pages.

Comment: Yes I can. It loads something at the start, maybe not openable from mobile?

Comment: I am trying to open link in web browser but it loads and then stops. all pages comes blank.

Comment: Working fine me also. If are still facing issue, here it she link - http://stuffandtech.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-quick-tip-adb-over-wifi.html

Comment: Yes working now. But in steps I am confuse. What is ADB and how can I install it? Anyone tried this solution?

Comment: Once you unstall Android SDK tool, you will get this adb.exe. You can find more details about ADB here - http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: @Surya - Thanks. and in that steps they saying "connect your device with computer? it means via wifi? if yes then how?